# Which dragon did we see in S07E06?

Tags: game-of-thrones, dragons

Major Spoiler for Season 7 Episode 6 *Beyond the Wall*

> We see Daenerys go off to rescue Jon and she took all three dragons with her. In the ensuing battle, the Night King killed, then transformed one of Daenerys' Dragons. It obviously wasn't Drogon since Daenerys was riding him, but I couldn't tell if it was Viserion or Rhaegal.

So which one was it?

Comment: Well, we did see all three of them... but there's really nothing much you can do in order to avoid spoilers for others.... It is still ridiculous though.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The closed captions indicate that it was Viserion. Daenerys watches as Viserion flies by screaming after having been hit.

[image: Dany watches Viserion screaming]

Answer (score 6):

It was Viserion, Rhaegal is more green-bronze color

Comment: The addition of images illustrating which dragon is which would go a long way toward improving this answer.

Comment: If you watch it with captioning, it tells you which one screams, etc.

Answer (score 3):

## <s>Vicerion</s> Viserion

This is spoken about explicitly in the script for the final episode of the season, released because it is up for an emmy.

> *A massive chunk of the Wall breaks free ahead of Tormund. The ice dragon glides away, and we get our first clear look at him, and at the Night King on his back. He's done the same thing to Viserion that he did to Craster's sons. Only those were babies, and this is a dragon.*
>
> <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf"</sub>

---

I've covered the distinctions between the three of them on [my answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172126/58193) but as a quick run down:

- Drogon: Black
- Rhaegal: Green
- Viserion: Gold

Looking at the dragon that was killed it is then clearly Viserion as it is neither black nor green so that leaves that one. It does look yellowish too but because of the blueish tint to the whole episode it's hard to tell.

[image: A young Viserion] [image: A dead Viserion]

On an out of universe reasoning HBO has released t[his 3D card](https://www.hbostore.co.uk/gift-guide/game-of-thrones/game-of-thrones-the-night-king-and-viserion-3d-card) titled "Game of Thrones The Night King and Viserion 3D Card" so It clears it up too.

[image: Game of Thrones The Night King and Viserion 3D Card]