# Does the show ever make clear which dragon is Viserion and which is Rhaegal?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/178695/86196) (S7E6 spoiler) the explanation is given that Viserion is the subject of that question, based on the colour of the dragon:

> "It may be as you say, blood of my blood," Dany replied gravely, "but he shall have a new name for this new life. I would name them all for those the gods have taken. **The green one shall be Rhaegal, for my valiant brother** who died on the green banks of the Trident. **The cream-and-gold I call Viserion. Viserys** was cruel and weak and frightened, yet he was my brother still. His dragon will do what he could not."
>   
> "And the black beast?" asked Ser Jorah Mormont.
>   
> **"The black," she said, "is Drogon."**
>   
> <sub>A Clash of Kings, Daenerys I</sub>

However, that is based on their description in the books. Drogon is more explicitly named in the show, so there is no doubt about him, but **does the show give any conclusive evidence on which dragon is which in universe?**

And let's disregard subtitles (Season 7 Episode 6 spoiler):

> [image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Yes

The show only appears to mention their names thrice throughout all of the seasons. The first is when Daenerys visits her dragons where she had locked them up but no indication is made to which is which.

> **Daenerys Targaryen:** Viserion? Rhaegal?
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 5 Episode 1, "The Wars to Come"</sub>

The second time is when her and Jon meet on Dragonstone and she tells him about the reasoning behind their names. Again no mention is made to which is which.

> **Jon Snow:** Amazing thing to see.
>
> **Daenerys Targaryen:** I named them for my brothers Viserys and Rhaegar. They're both gone now.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Episode 3, "Queen's Justice"</sub>

Lastly, in Season 8 Episode 4 Tormund is asking Jon how he's going to get to Dragonstone, Jon says by horse as Rhaegal needs to heal. At this moment in time Viserion has become Vicerion and has died twice so only Drogon and Rhaegal are left.

> **Tormund Giantsbane:** You're not gonna ride the dragon south?
>
> **Jon Snow:** Just a horse. Rhaegal needs to heal. He doesn't need me weighing him down.
>
> **Tormund Giantsbane:** You weigh as much as two fleas fucking.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 5, "The Last of the Stakrs"</sub>

Comment: `Rhaegal needs to heal.` Ah, but that's cheating. That's after D&D used the subtitles to figure out which one was Viserion. `;)`